# PHP - preg_match_all - Loose email match pattern that allows spaces and double @

Tags: php, email, preg-match-all

I am going through our old site files and data that has our members emails and correspondence for 10 years.

I am extracting all of the email addresses (and botched email entries) and adding them to our new sites db.

It was a beginner attempt cms and had no error checking and validation.

So, I am having trouble matching emails with spaces and double @.

jam @ spa  ces1.com

jam@spac  es2.com

jam@@doubleats.org

I have constructed this loose regex that intentionally allows for a whole bunch of incorrect email formats but, the above three are examples of ones I can't figure out.

Here is my current "working" code:

```
$pattern1= '([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)';
$pattern2='\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b';
$pattern="/$pattern1|$pattern2/i";
$isago = preg_match_all($pattern,$text,$matches);
    if ($isago) {.......
```

I need another pattern that would allow the three email examples above to be recognized as email addresses. (actual validation comes later)

Also, is there is any other patterns I could use that would allow me to recognize possible emails in the files?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third case you can change your `@` to `@{1,2}`.
For the first and second you can add a space in your regex `pattern1`:

```
$pattern1= '([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@{1,2}([ ]+|)([ a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)';
$pattern2='\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@{1,2}[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b';
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried a very similar change but, you taught me something. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is like a joke I know... but, how about this RegEx:

`/[\S ]+@[\S ]+\.[\S ]+/i`

That's works for you? I'm tested it in a document and match the three mails.

Comment: This will accept characters (besides space) that are not valid email characters, or even "   @    "

Answer (score 0):

For general purpose you should use something like this:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9\._]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\._]+/i
```

With that you would match all the emails, even separated by newline or commas.